# How to print Global:view using php code in drupal view?

Tags: views

I have two views called **contents** where I am displaying Albums and videos, another view is **photos count** where I am displaying photos count of specific album. I have included "photos count" view into the "contents" view using Global:view now i want to print the included view using php code only if the content type is "ALBUM". I have written below code which is not working. What's wrong with my code?

```
$result="";
$nid=$row->nid; 
$result=count(views_get_view_result('album_count','panel_pane_3 ', $nid));

$node = node_load($nid);
$type = $node->type; 
if($type=="album")
{
  print "Total Number of Photos : ".$row->view;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be printing or otherwise looking at `$result`?

Comment: But I want the included view to be printed only for album content type nodes.

Comment: what jimajamma is saying is - you assign $result a value (well actually two values), but you never use that value. What was the point of getting a count you don't use?

Comment: does it run anything at all - ie. if you print $type outside of a condition, does it print a value, and what does it print?

Comment: Yes, it prints the content type correctly i.e "album".

Comment: And yes I had assigned value to the $result just to display count of photos, But its displaying count 1 for all albums even album contains more.